# Programatically generate list of labels and colors for ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to colour a `ggplot2` `geom_line()` graph in which I want each line to have a different colour and the legend label reflects the year the data represents.  I've successfully manually created a list of colours to assign each year using the rainbow colour table. However, I have a much larger number of years to populate and I'd like to avoid typing each one by hand.  I am unable to recreate the manual entry with a seq statement.

The following is the manual code:

```
col_a <- c("2009" = rnbw[1],  "2010" = rnbw[2])
```

My attempt to recreate this using seq is:

```
col_b <- c(paste(2009+seq(0:1), "=" , "rnbw[",seq(1:10),"],", sep=""))
```

How can I modify this above line such that `col_b` is identical to `col_a`?

Comment: `setNames(rnbw, 2008 + seq_len(length(rnbw)))`

Comment: Or for a 30% speed improvement (of something that is already nearly-instantaneous ... say it with me: early/unnecessary code optimization), you can use `\`names<-\`(rbnw, 2008 + seq_len(length(rbnw)))`. (Those are indeed backticks, and they are necessary to use functions that are really intended to be used on the left-hand side of an assignment operator.)

Comment: Have you tried adding `+ scale_color_viridis_d()` to your ggplot? Need the `viridis` package.

Comment: @r2evans.  That solves the problem! Thanks.